# Не получается вывести данные xpath для парсера

Tags: php, парсер, xpath

Не получается вывести данные xpath для парсера. как можно это сделать. есть мысли?

```
<?php
    
    include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
    $array=array('https://www.compulog.ru/');
    include_once('phpQuery-onefile.php');
    
    
    
    $url='https://www.compulog.ru/';    
    function parse($url)
    {
    $dom = new DomDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($url);
    $xpath = new DomXPath( $dom );
    $_res = $xpath->query("//span");
    
    return $_res;
    }  
    parse($url);
 ?>
```

Comment: <?php

include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$array=array('https://www.compulog.ru/');
include_once('phpQuery-onefile.php');


 function parse($url)
{
  

$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($url);
$xpath = new DomXPath( $dom );
$_res = $xpath->query("//span");

return $_res; 

   
}

$links=array();
foreach($array  as $url)
{
  
$tel=parse($url);  
 var_dump($tel);  

  
  
}

?>

Comment: так тоже пробывал  комент  выше

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DOMDocument::loadHTML](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/domdocument.loadhtml.php) в качестве значения для первого аргумента принимает строку, содержащую HTML разметку, а не как у вас, - url внешнего ресурса.

Исправьте вашу ф-ю:

```
function parse($url)
{
    ...
    $content = file_get_contents($url);
    $dom->loadHTML($content, LIBXML_NOERROR);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, буду знать. Можете подсказать как вывести  данные из  переменной $_res?

Comment: Если мой ответ помог, то примите его ))